# How to extend Rectangle class in Dart?

Tags: inheritance, dart

I wanna to create my custom rectangle class which is extended from Rectangle class.
I've error that class Rectangle doesn't have declarative constructor 'Rectangle', I have seen source of Rectangle class and there are constant constructor. 
Is it possible to do it ? I thought that possible solution is using composition instead of inheritance. Thanks for answers.

```dart
    part of Plot;

    class PlotRectangle extends Rectangle{

      // Rectangle<int> rectangle; // as variant use composition
      String color = "red"; 

      PlotRectangle(int left, int top, int width, int height): super.Rectangle(left, top, width, height){

      }

      PlotRectangle.withColor(int left, int top, int width, int height, this.color): super.Rectangle(left, top, width, height){
        this.color = color;
      }

      void setColor(String color){
        this.color = color;
      }  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tried it and worked

```dart
library x;

import 'dart:math';

class PlotRectangle<T extends num> extends Rectangle<T> {
  PlotRectangle(T left, T top, T width, T height) : super(left, top, width, height);

  String color = 'red';

  factory PlotRectangle.fromPoints(Point<T> a, Point<T> b) {
    T left = min(a.x, b.x);
    T width = max(a.x, b.x) - left;
    T top = min(a.y, b.y);
    T height = max(a.y, b.y) - top;
    return new PlotRectangle<T>(left, top, width, height);
  }

  PlotRectangle.withColor(T left, T top, T width, T height, this.color) : super(left, top, width, height);

  @override
  String toString() => '${super.toString()}, $color';
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  var r = new PlotRectangle(17, 50, 30, 28);
  print(r);
  var rc = new PlotRectangle.withColor(17, 50, 30, 28, 'blue');
  print(rc);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Günter already showed, it is very possible.

To be a little bit more specific, the error in your code is the call to the super constructor:

`super.Rectangle(left, top, width, height)` should be `super(left, top, width, height)`.

Your syntax tries to call the named constructor "Rectangle", which would be equivalent to `new Rectangle.Rectangle` - that constructor doesn't exist. You want to call the "normal" constructor (`new Rectangle`), which is called by just using `super`.